# Computed getters and setters for dynamic options

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I use Vuex with my Vue components. When my components have static fields that are editedtable, they are easily handled with computed properties:

```
computed: {
  text: {
    get() {
      return ...
    },
    set(value) {
      this.$store.commit...
    },
  },
},

<input type="text" v-model="text">
```

However, how should this be done when I render a list of options that need to be bound?

```
options = [
  {
    value: ...,
    text: ...,
  },
  {
    value: ...,
    text: ...,
  },
  ...
];

<input type="text" v-model="option.text" v-for="option in options">
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define mutations for the options, like "addOption", "editOption", etc...

Than optionally ( but recommended ) define an options component. Bind events to call the mutations.

A good simple example provided by vuex is available here:
https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/todomvc

Particularly look at the todo component. It is in charge of a single item from the todo list.
https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/examples/todomvc/components/Todo.vue

and how they work with the list in the app component.
https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/examples/todomvc/components/App.vue

And these are their mutations. See how they edit and add and delete list items.
https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/examples/todomvc/store/mutations.js

I can't have a shorter answer, moving to vuex ( vue + redux methodology ) requires a shift in thinking and architecture.

Answer (score -1):

You can model these options as [data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) in your vue instance and use them in HTML as you have mentioned.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
     options: [
       {
         value: ...,
         text: ...,
       },
       {
         value: ...,
         text: ...,
       },
       ... 
     ]
  }
})
```

And in HTML:

```
<input type="text" v-model="option.text" key="option.value" v-for="option in options">
```

I have added a [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) attribute as well along with `v-for` so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key attribute for each item. An ideal value for key would be the unique id of each item.

Comment: This is the pure Vue way of doing this but with Vuex mutations need to be done without directly mutating the source object (using `v-model`).

Comment: It depends if you have vuex model, the way I have told I via Vue instance data, that is not vuex data.

Comment: This is how I had it before I switched to Vuex. However, I asked specifically for a Vuex implementation.